# How do I copy controls from one panel to another and keep aligned?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5, panel

I have two forms with same size and each one with a panel inside with same location value. On `form1` I have a button that copy all the controls from the `form2` to `form1` on `onclick` event. It works, sort of, it copy all the controls but they aren't aligned on the `form1` as it in the `form2`.

form1:

[image]

form2:

[image]

And the code to `change` button:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form2 = new Form2();

            this.panel1.Controls.Clear();

            foreach(Control control in form2.panel1.GetAllControls())
                this.panel1.Controls.Add(control);
        }
```

code for `GetAllControls()` compiler extension:

```
 public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(this Control root)
        {
            foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
            {
                foreach (Control child in GetAllControls(control))
                {
                    yield return child;
                }
            }
            yield return root;
        }
```

After I hit the change button I get this (unaligned labels):

[image]

Note that the location doesn't match well to as defined in the `form2` (I created both with same size and location to match exactly). Why is that and how can I fix this?

edit: To access the `panel1` from `form2` I made its modifier `public`

Comment: You are not reconstructing the nesting correctly. (Read it was not as it looks from the beginning..) Are you sure you copy not move them controls, btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the type of alignment mismatch...  It appears the anchoring is an issue for the 3 controls... Please check Anchor property of the 3 controls in form2 at design time.

But I would suggest you another approach - instead of copying individual controls,  copy the entire parent control.
So,  just add panel1 from form2 to panel1 of form1 and set the dock style (of this pannel being added) to fill